# Rate limit exim per user basis

Tags: smtp, exim, rate-limiting

How can I implement "rate limit" in Exim so that every user in my exim can send specific number of emails per day.

List A of Users can send 100 emails per day and the list B of users can send 500 emails per day.

Answer (score 7):

Expanding on HBruijn's answer, I recommend this ACL segment:

```
# Keep authenticated users under control
deny authenticated = *
     set acl_c_msg_limit=${lookup{$sender_address}nwildlsearch{/etc/exim/send_limits}}
     ratelimit = $acl_c_msg_limit / 1d / strict / $authenticated_id
```

Then you create the /etc/exim/send_limits file and have this in there:

```
# Commented lines and blank lines are ignored
# Format is     EMAIL: LIMIT
user1@domain1.com: 100
user2@domain1.com: 200
user3@domainXX.com: 100

# Must be the last line, this is the default limit
*@*: 50
```

This is untested, but it should get you headed in the right direction.

Comment: Where in the ACL section should you put this?

Comment: I don't know why but the last line of send_limits file '\*@\*' doesn't match as default.

Answer (score 2):

The [manual](http://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch-access_control_lists.html#useratlim) has a configuration example for a user based rate limiting setting:

```
# Keep authenticated users under control
deny authenticated = *
     ratelimit = 100 / 1d / strict / $authenticated_id
```

That restricts authenticated senders to 100 messages per day but which would also be global for all authenticated users.

Comment: You can enhance the answer by on the line before the ratelimit, adding a set acl_c_msg_limit=${lookup{$sender_address}nwildlsearch{/etc/exim/send_limits}}, then use that variable in the place of the "100" in your ratelimit.  In the /etc/exim/send_limits, have AT THE END of the file "*@*: 10" (assuming that 10 is a good default).  Any other email address, including using wildcards, can be to set the limit to 100 or 200 as he desires.

Comment: That makes a much better answer than just leaving it as a comment.

Comment: Maybe it's a stupid question, but, where should I insert this settings? Which is the right ACL? I'm using ubuntu server and it has exim configuration separated in many files, I'm a bit confused how to use this fragmented configuration.